# There is a name for this technique of mapping url?

Tags: url, mapping

Instead construct the url in this mode:

```
http://www.mysite.com/user/view?name=michele&age=30
```

write something like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/user/view/name/michele/age/30
```

or

```
http://www.mysite.com/user/view,name-michele,age-30
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is called REST:

**Representational state transfer (REST)** is an architectural style consisting of a coordinated set of architectural constraints applied to components, connectors, and data elements, within a distributed hypermedia system. REST ignores the details of component implementation and protocol syntax in order to focus on the roles of components, the constraints upon their interaction with other components, and their interpretation of significant data elements.

Web service APIs that adhere to the **REST** constraints are called **RESTful.**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|                         Resource                         |                                                          GET                                                          |                                        PUT                                         |                                                             POST                                                              |                     DELETE                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Collection URI, such as http://example.com/resources     | List the URIs and perhaps other details of the collection's members.                                                  | Replace the entire collection with another collection.                             | Create a new entry in the collection. The new entry's URI is assigned automatically and is usually returned by the operation. | Delete the entire collection.                  |
| Element URI, such as http://example.com/resources/item17 | Retrieve a representation of the addressed member of the collection, expressed in an appropriate Internet media type. | Replace the addressed member of the collection, or if it doesn't exist, create it. | Not generally used. Treat the addressed member as a collection in its own right and create a new entry in it.                 | Delete the addressed member of the collection. |
+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

More:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer